# how to get the reference for checkbox element from both parent and child grids

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have got requirement like i need to find the parent grid row checkbox and if parent grid row checkbox is checked then i need to set all child grid checkboxes to true for that parent grid row checkbox for that purpose I have done like this....

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnMove').click(function () {                                        
        var parentgrid = $('#GridParent').data('kendoGrid');  
        var childGrid = $('#GridParent').closest(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid");               
        var Count = $('#Gridparent').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.total();
        alert(Count);
      for (i = 0; i < Count; i++) 
     {
          var isChecked = parentgrid.tbody.find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').find('td').find('.chkbxq').is(':checked');
          alert(isChecked); // here i need to get the property of parent grid row checkbox and I am not getting this alert....                  
          if (isChecked == true)
          {
             var allchildgridchkboxes = childGrid.tbody.find('td').find('chkbx');
             alert(allchildgridchkboxes); // i am not getting this alert     
             // here i need to set the all checkboxes checked property to true
          }

     }     
   });
 });
</script>
```

and this is my view where i am defining checkboxes in grid ...

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Topco.TopMapp.MVC.Models.CostPageSearch>()
        .Name("Gridparent")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox' onclick='grdChkBoxClick(this);' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox' />").Width(30);
            columns.Bound(e => e.CostPage).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.Description).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.VendorName).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.BillTypeDirect).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.BillTypeWarehouse).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.VendorName).Width(100);    
        })
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("client-template")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:480px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(6)
            .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Employees", "CostPageDisplay"))
        )
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
)
    <script id="client-template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
         @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Topco.TopMapp.MVC.Models.ItemsDescriptionModel>()
            .Name("grid_#=CostPage#")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox' onclick='grdChkBoxClick(this); 'class='chkbxq' type='checkbox'/>").Width(30);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ItemId).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ItemDescription).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.BrandCode).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.PackSize).Width(100);
            })
           .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
               .Ajax()
               .PageSize(5)
               .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", "CostPageDisplay" , new { employeeID = "#=CostPage#" }))
           )
           .ToClientTemplate()
   )
    </script>
<script>
    function dataBound() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
        //alert('1');
    }
</script>
```

would any one pls help on this ... how to find the  parent grid row checkbox checked and how to get all checkboxes for child grid ....

pls look at the image ...i need to get the  checkbox reference for both grids

[image]

**UPDATE :**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnMove').click(function () {
            debugger;
            alert("button clicked");
            var parentgrid = $('#GridParent').data('kendoGrid');       
            var count = $('#Gridparent').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.total();
            alert(count);
            var ischeckedone = parentgrid.tbody.find('td').find('.chkbxq').is(':checked');
            alert(ischeckedone);
            var rows = parentgrid.table.find('>tbody>tr').find('tr.k-state-selected').dataSource.total();
            alert(rows);
            //var sel = rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML;
            //alert(sel);        
            //var gridchild = parentgrid.parents("[data-role=grid]").data("kendoGrid");
            //var COUNT = parentgrid.parents("[data-role=grid]").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.total();
            //var childGrid = $('#GridParent').closest(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid");
            //var childgrid = parentgrid.detailCell.find('>.k-grid').data().kendoGrid;                
            //var anothercount = $('#GridParent').closest(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.total();
            //alert(anothercount);
           // var childrows = parentgrid.detailCell.find('>.k-grid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.total();
           // alert(childrows);
            var chekbox = parentgrid.table.find('tr').find('td:first input').find('.chkbxq').is(':checked');
            alert(chekbox);
            for (i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
               // var isChecked = parentgrid.tbody.find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').find('td').find('.chkbxq').is(':checked');
                var chekbox = parentgrid.table.find('tr').find('td:first input').find('.chkbxq').is(':checked');
                alert(chekbox);// din't worked
                alert(isChecked);// din't worked
                if (isChecked == true)
                {
                    var allchildgridchkboxes = childGrid.tbody.find('td').find('chkbx');
                    alert(allchildgridchkboxes); // din't worked
                }              
            }     
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you create jsfiddle with the result HTML code

Comment: I have tried that but it was giving some errors....

Comment: @pratap i just post my code in demo link please close `html` and `css` tab so you can see demo perfectly.

Comment: @Jaimin this is done in button click event, but i need to do not in button click event ...pls see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180915/checkbox-event-is-not-firing-with-jquery

Comment: @pratap i just post my code.

Comment: @pratap i just update my code for this question.

Comment: Place a generated HTML for that cshtml file. With a HTML in hands is a much more easy way to delve into a solution

Comment: @pratap see the chat.Post some comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my code i have `checkbox` in `header` not in `td` but this help you to find corresponding `child grid`  `checkbox` to,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#grid12').on("click", ".chkbxq", function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var selected = $this.is(':checked');
        var id = $this.attr('id');
        var value = id.replace('checkbox_', '');
        var rowIndex = $this.parent().index();
        var cellIndex = $this.parent().parent().index();
        var grid = $("#grid12").data("kendoGrid");
        var datatItem = grid.dataItem(grid.tbody.find('tr:eq(' + cellIndex + ')'));

         var childgridid = $('.k-detail-row').find('td.k-detail-cell').find('div.k-grid').attr('id');
          var valurchildgrid = childgridid.replace('grid_', '');
          var childrowscount = $('div[id*="grid_' + valurchildgrid + '"]').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.total();

        var check = $('.k-detail-row').find('td.k-detail-cell').find('div.k-grid').find('table').find('tbody').find('input[id*="checkboxChild_' + value + '"]').each(function () {
            if (selected == true) {
                $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
            else {
                $(this).attr('checked', false);
            }
        });        



    });
});
</script>
```

**Grid View**

```
<script id="client-template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">

         @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TwoModelInSinglePageModel.SampleGridModel>()
                    .Name(" grid_#=CostPage#")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input id='checkboxChild_#=inx#' 'class='checkchild' type='checkbox'/>").Width(30);
                columns.Bound(o => o.SampleDescriptionGrid).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.SampleCodeGrid).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.SampleItemsGrid).Width(100);
            })
           .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
               .Ajax()
               .PageSize(5)
                       .Read(read => read.Action("ReadGrid", "Test"))
           )
           .ToClientTemplate()
   )
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("GridListView", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
{ 

@*<input id="Submit1" type="button" value="SubmitValue" />*@
    <input id="btnsubmit" type="button" value="SubmitValue" />
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TwoModelInSinglePageModel.SampleModel>()
    .Name("grid12")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.studentclass).HeaderTemplate("<input id='selectall' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox'  />").ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox_#=inx#' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox' />");
        columns.Bound(p => p.SampleDescription);
        columns.Bound(p => p.SampleCode);
        columns.Bound(p => p.SampleItems);
    })
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("client-template")
        .AutoBind(true) // here I am disabling automatic binding at page load
       .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Test"))
     )
  )
```

In Child Grid pass `unique-key`  in each child `checkbox`. `INX` is our `unique-key`.Pass `Unique-key` like this `id='checkboxChild_#=inx#'`.

This is demo link http://jsbin.com/ivoqup/3/edit

Comment: many thanks for this answer ..i need to find the data part of child grid something like this  `var childGrid = $('#GridParent').closest(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid");  `  I hav used this one but I am getting null actually I have got the data in child grid in hierarchy ....

Comment: yes jaimin ....we don't have any checkboxes in header we do have got check boxes in every row in parent grid  and every child grid row ...

Comment: i just seen `image` you post in your question that's why.ok i try what you just said and let you know.

Comment: many Thanks in advance i will update the question with what i have tried up to now ...

Comment: @pratap in hierarchy grid if you want to find all child grid you have to open all corresponding parent grid.If you open only one parent grid and you want to find all child grid in that page you can't find that,Because Child grid is only display when you open there particular parent,otherwise there property is `display:block`.

Comment: is there any possibility to access the child grid near to corresponding  row (i mean by using reference row number .. at the moment i am posting same child grid to all parent grid rows later on if we connected with database we need to populate different child grids for different parent grid rows...)

Comment: I am getting error like this `0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'tbody' is null or not an object`  at this line           `var ischeckedone = parentgrid.tbody.find('td').find('.chkbxq').is(':checked');` and this is implemented code ... `var parentgrid = $('#GridParent').data('kendoGrid');`

Comment: @pratap Child grid is not grid it's bind like tr. So try this
`$('#grid').find(".k-detail-row").find('td.k-detail-cell').find('[type="checkbox"]')` checkbox.

Comment: Or this for `$('#grid').find(".k-detail-row").find('td.k-detail-cell')` for child grid select.

Comment: i am just checking checkbox in parent grid first row by using this code `var parentgrid = $('#GridParent').data('kendoGrid'); and var ischeckedone = parentgrid.tbody.find('td').find('.chkbxq').is(':checked');` it giving error ...

Comment: @pratap used this if this `parentgrid.tbody.find('td').find('.chkbxq').is(':checked');` give you error  `$("#GridParent").find('tbody').find('td').find('.chkbxq').is(':checked')`

Comment: Or you use
`$("#GridParent").find('tbody').find('td') .find('[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')`

Comment: if you have free time let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35128/discussion-between-pratap-k-and-jaimin)