# checkbox event is not firing with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have got checkbox row in parent grid and checkbox row in child grid as well in [Hierarchy grid mode using kendo UI](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/hierarchy.html). the architecture is like this...

I have got four rows in parent grid,in that one column is checkbox and for every parent row i have got one child grid with 4 rows in it and one checkbox column as well...

If i click the checkbox in parent grid row i need to access the checkboxes in child grid column related to this row only and need to set the checked attribute as true for that child grid.....

for that I am accessing the parent grid checkbox like this ..

this is javascript function

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.chkbxq').live('click', function (e) {
        alert('1'); // this alert is not firing 
        var checkchildgrid = $('#Gridparent').find(".k-detail-row").find('td.k-detail-cell').find('[type="checkbox‌​"]').is(':checked');
        alert(checkchildgrid);
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {    
            checkchildgrid.attr('checked', 'checked');
        } else {
            checkchildgrid.attr('checked', false);
        }    
    });        
</script>
```

and this is hierarchy grid code ....

```
    @model IEnumerable<Topco.TopMapp.MVC.Models.CostPageSearch>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Topco.TopMapp.MVC.Models.CostPageSearch>()
        .Name("Gridparent")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input id='chqprnt' class= 'chkbxq' type='checkbox'/>").Width(30);
            columns.Bound(e => e.CostPage).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.Description).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.VendorName).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.BillTypeDirect).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.BillTypeWarehouse).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.VendorName).Width(100);

        })
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable()
        .Scrollable()
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("client-template")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:480px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(6)
            .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Employees", "CostPageDisplay"))
        )
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
)
    <script id="client-template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
         @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Topco.TopMapp.MVC.Models.ItemsDescriptionModel>()
            .Name("grid_#=CostPage#")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox'  class='chkbx' type='checkbox' />").Width(30);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ItemId).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ItemDescription).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.BrandCode).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.PackSize).Width(100);
            })
           .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
               .Ajax()
               .PageSize(5)
               .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", "CostPageDisplay" , new { employeeID = "#=CostPage#" }))
           )
           .Pageable()
           .Sortable()
           .ToClientTemplate()
   )
    </script>
<script>
    function dataBound() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
        //alert('1');
    }
</script>
```

but when i click on the checkbox in parent grid the click event is not firing ...

would any one pls suggest any ideas and solutions with this problem that would be very grateful to me.....

many thanks in advance ...

**EDIT :** would you pls look at the image below that is where i placed the checkbox and clicking on that checkbox does not firing event ...

[image]

Comment: live is removed in `jquery 1.9` , use `.on` instead

Comment: And wrap in `$(function() {---}`

Comment: I am using jquery 1.7.1.js version ..

Comment: still i am not able to fire that event ...

Comment: @MohammadAdil would you pls look at the image where i have placed that checbox and i am trying fire checked event for that

Comment: @mplungjan  would you pls look at the image where i have placed that checbox and i am trying fire checked event for that  and  event i put that entile function inside jquery wrapper ...but its still not firing ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
 $('#Gridparent').on("click", ".chkbxq", function (e) {

       var selected = $(this).is(':checked');

        var grid = $("#grid12").data("kendoGrid");


        if (selected == true) {

            var check = $('.k-detail-row').find('td.k-detail-cell').find('div.k-grid').find('table').find('tbody').find('[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true);
            var asd = check.is(':checked');
            alert(asd);
        }

        });
```

Use grid click.

Comment: Jaimin I am getting same problem like if i select checkbox in parent grid row it will selects the child grid row checkboxes( no issue at here) but it also selecets all other parent grid row checkboxes  also (issue is here )

Comment: one more question i would like to ask i am not able to get the row count  for child grid  would you pls help on this ...

Comment: hmm i have rectified that one its working fine now ... i need to loop through all rows in child grid for that i need to get child grid row count .....i have tried these ones but dint worked `var childrowscount = $('.k-detail-row').find('td.k-detail-cell').find('div.k-grid').find('table').length;` and `var anothergridcount = $('#GridParent').closest(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.total();` and `var childrows = parentgrid.detailCell.find('>.k-grid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.total();` these ones

Comment: Worked great for me. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me with Tag Helpers! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I imagine it should be coded - disclaimer I do not know Kendo at all

If we need to process the checkboxes as you WRITE, we can do

```
$(function() {
  $('.chkbxq').on('click', function (e) {
    var checked = this.checked;
    $('#Gridparent').find(".k-detail-row").find('td.k-detail-cell').find('[type="checkbox‌​"]').each(function()
      this.checked=checked; // toggle
    });    
  });    
});
```

If the content is ajaxed in, you need

```
$(function() {
  $("#Gridparent").on('click','.chkbxq', function (e) {
    var checked = this.checked;
    $(this).find(".k-detail-row").find('td.k-detail-cell').find('[type="checkbox‌​"]').each(function()
      this.checked=checked; // toggle
    });    
  });    
});
```

**NOTE** .find works all the way down the dom, so perhaps you just want

```
$(this).find('[type="checkbox‌​"]').each(function()
```

Comment: thanks , I am able to fire that event but in side I am not bale to set those ones are true....would you pls help  this function is not working ...  `$(this).find(".k-detail-row").find('td.k-detail-cell').find('[type="checkbox‌​"]').each(function()`

Comment: No without seeing the rendered html. Can you make a jsfiddle.net with the actual generated html?

Answer (score 0):

see following if it helps:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

   $('.chkbxq').on('click', function (e) {

    alert('1'); // this alert is not firing 

    var checkchildgrid = $('#Gridparent').find(".k-detail-row").find('td.k-detail-cell').find('[type="checkbox‌​"]').prop('checked');
    alert(checkchildgrid);

    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {    
        checkchildgrid.prop('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        checkchildgrid.prop('checked', false);
    }    
});
```

i hope it helps.

Comment: I am getting error in ie8 like  Object doesn't support this property or method .....

Comment: I have put debugger inside this click function that is why I am getting that error , now i removed debugger i am not getting any error in ie8 ... but I am not getting that alert  also ...

Comment: $('.chkbxq') instead of this if you change to that $('#chqprnt'), not firing in that case too???