# Get cell value from kendo grid using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to get the kendo grid cell value using jquery function?Am new to kendo grid

```
{field:abc,title:values}
```

I need the abc value in javascript or jquery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125609/how-to-get-the-reference-for-checkbox-element-from-both-parent-and-child-grids

Answer (score 8):

I assume your using single row selection for the Grid. This piece of code will grab any value you need off of the selected row.

```
$('#ProposalGrid').click(function () {
    var gview = $(this).data("kendoGrid");
    var selectedItem = gview.dataItem(gview.select());
    var Guid = selectedItem.YourPropertyName;

})
```

selectedItem gives you access to all the properties on your model

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still looking for an answer then you can try using following steps:

**Note:** Basically KendoGrid all rows have it's unique uid property assigned for identify each row. So if you are having uid then you can follow these steps:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

var tr = grid.dataSource.getByUid("your-row-uid");

var yourFieldValue = tr.yourFieldName;
```

**Even you can get value throught following steps:**

**First :**

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
```

**Second :**

```
var dataItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
```

or

```
var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(event.target).closest("tr"));
```

or

```
var dataItem = grid.dataItem("tr.k-grid-edit-row");
```

**Third:**

```
var yourFieldValue = dataItem.yourFieldName;
```